# How do I get out of the very first room in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

I was able to take all of the items out of the storage container, but now it looks like I need to find some kind of fuel to power my trip to the surface of the planet.

[image]

How do I get out of this room?

Comment: Fuel is used to fly to different planets, it is not needed to power the teleport.

Comment: It still never ceases to amuse me how many new Starbound players can't figure out how to escape their spaceship.

Comment: Dude. I had this exact same problem the first time I played. I think they've made it a little more obvious than it was back in the day. Before I'm pretty sure you *had* to stand on the pad (which isn't obviously a teleportation pad) and push a button without prompt. It's weird to have a combination "mouse hover + keyboard button press" be something you just guess to do. Of course that was back when teleporting would just respawn you back in your ship 4/5 times you tried to go down to the surface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two options:

- walk on top of the blue round (square in 2D) teleporter to the left and then press E while hovering your mouse over it, or
- click the down arrow ([image: V]) in the corner while standing anywhere in the ship.

Answer (score -3):

Click the "beam down" button. It is located directly above the button with an `!` on it. This works for beta versions and 1.0

Comment: Again, your answer adds nothing worthwhile and is extremely late.